# ajax + php Передача переменной без перезагрузки странички

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться. Собственно необходимо вывести значение переменной в блоке после нажатия на ссылку. Но это конечная задача, с ней думаю я разберусь. Сейчас все максимально упрощено. Этот вопрос я задаю что бы понять механизм работы, мне не обязательно видеть готовое решение. 
Вот мой код, и он не работает, подскажите почему.

index.php

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="getajax">Get Ajax</button>
<div id="ajax">/*ожидание вывода*/</div>
<script>
$('#getajax').live('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          data:'do=yes',
          url:"request.php",
          success:function(in){  
           $('#ajax').html(in);   
          }

          });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

request.php

```html
<?php if($_POST['do']=="yes"):?>
<?php echo "Ответ от request";?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Заранее благодарю вас за ответ, желательно ткнуть лицом в ошибку и сказать как ее исправить. Ссылки на мануал мне давать не нужно, спасибо, я его читал, видимо как то не так читал.

Comment: `live()` ? это что за древняя версия jquery Вам вспомнилась? `on('click', function())`

Comment: Попробуйте так:
`$.post( "request.php", { do: "yes"}).done(function( data ) {
    $('#ajax').html(data);
  });`

Comment: Дело в том что jqery я вообще толком не знаю, оно в общем то мне на данном этапе и не очень нужно, есть готовый php скрипт который мне нужно привести к работе без перезагрузки, потому хочу увидеть толковый пример. Это то что мне удалось собрать после чтения мануалов но работать оно не хочет

Comment: `live()` функция помечена  Deprecated в 1.7 jquery, а в 1.9 уже удалена, вы же используете 1.11

Comment: Спасибо ваш комментарий очень помог)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том что вы используете пример от другой версии JQuery. Функция [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) удалена еще в 1.9, сейчас следует использовать [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Ну и для того чтоб отправить POST есть специализированная функция [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Работающий скрипт должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$('#getajax').on('click',function(){
    $.post( "request.php", { do: "yes"})
     .done(function(data) { 
             $('#ajax').html(data); 
   });
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, да это решение.  ))

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: И еще вопрос если можно, в моем основном коде button id генерируется в цикле php и их может быть неограниченное кол-во, и их все нужно обработать этой функцией $('#getajax').on('click',function()
но в коде так же есть button id которые обрабатывать не нужно, подскажите как это реализовать?
Что то мне подсказывает что разумнее кнопку будет заменить на ссылку, или нет?

Comment: <a href="#" onClick="set_mode_view(<?php echo $productid[$key_catalog]['id'] ?>);"> 

function set_mode_view(id)
{
....
}

Что то мне подсказывает смотреть в этом направление

Comment: id не должно быть несколько одинаковых на одной странице, надо использовать или class или data-какой-нибудьидентифаер. проставляйте класс только на те button на которые нужно. Как пример, чтобы поймать все `<button  data-shouldrequest="yes">` селектор будет выглядет так: `$("button:data(shouldrequest)")`

Comment: @Alex можете и в таком направлении. Но лучше нет :)

Comment: Проблема в том что как раз этот уникальный id должен передаваться в request

Comment: это как раз не проблема :) `data-anydata="anything your heart desires"` специально для этого сделаны все эти data-* аттрибуты.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!) Вы помогли закончить скрипт )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w6ufxjof/ вот как-то так я имел ввиду